# Template plugin(?) to jump to next occurance of '<++>'

Tags: cursor-movement

I just noticed that my current box with vim is missing a crucial feature, but I am unable to bring it back.

A long time ago I had a vim setup where I could press `Ctrl+J` (IIRC) and then my cursor would jump to the next occurance of `<++>`. Actually, this was sort of a template system where I could put a name between the `+` signs, to tell me/the user about the information that has to go there.

For instance I could copy paste the following text to any new document:

```
Hello <+name+>,
how are you today? I am feeling <+feeling+>.
Hope to hear from you soon
<+signature+>
```

and then I could `Ctrl+J` and vim would jump to `<+name+>` in insert mode and with my typing I would overwrite `<+name+>`. Then I'd press `Ctrl+J` again and vim would jump to `<+feeling+>` in insert mode so that I could overwrite that and so on and so forth.

Does anybody know that functionality and how I can install it on my current machine? I am fairly certain I did not code that myself ...

Answer (score 1):

I remember two plugins with this feature:

- vim-latex implements jump on `<c-j>`.
- my [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets) plugin implements jump on `<c-j>` with vim, or on `<m-del>` with gvim -- default keybindings can be changed. [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template) that relies on lh-brackets exploits this feature to implement its placeholders.

PS: I don't provide here the underlying code as it's quite complex, and not that trivial to implement correctly.

Comment: Yes, I just found it. After posting this I remembered I had a latex package installed and when adding `latex` as search term, I got a result for my Google search. [The functionality as I know it is mentioned here.](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-macros.html)